# Regex for splitting string into arraylist in java

Tags: java, regex, string, arraylist

I am to split a string and need to create a List.So I have to use the below syntax.
List myList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Regex"));

My Input String

```
1/6/2015 11:30:29   ERROR   No connection.Verify the server is running. http://10.23.64.86:8080/-location/locations/
ErrorUrl : file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/app/index.html#/TrainStatus
Error   
    at Scope.$digest (file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12514:31)
    at Scope.$apply (file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12806:24)
    at done (file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8379:45),
1/6/2015 11:30:29   ERROR   No connection.Verify the server is running. http://10.23.64.86:8080/-location/locations/
ErrorUrl : file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/app/index.html#/TrainStatus
Error
    at file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/app/scripts/controllers/dTrainStatusSearchController.js:271:118
    at file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8120:11  
    at done (file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8379:45)
```

and I need to split it into two like below

```
1/6/2015 11:30:29   ERROR   No connection.Verify the server is running. http://10.23.64.86:8080/-location/locations/
ErrorUrl : file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/app/index.html#/TrainStatus
Error   
    at Scope.$digest (file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12514:31)
    at Scope.$apply (file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12806:24)
    at done (file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8379:45)
```

,

```
1/6/2015 11:30:29   ERROR   No connection.Verify the server is running. http://10.23.64.86:8080/-location/locations/
ErrorUrl : file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/app/index.html#/TrainStatus
Error
    at file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/app/scripts/controllers/dTrainStatusSearchController.js:271:118
    at file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8120:11  
    at done (file:///C:/%20CODE/ddi/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8379:45)
```

Anyone help me to form exact regex to split the above string and put it a list.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an easy solution if this is the only `String` you are attempting to split.

Something like this would work for the input `String` you provided in your question:

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(yourString.split(","));
```

You can use http://regexpal.com/ to help you in the future.

Comment: ","may come inside of each element.So I unable to use that approach

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex like this : `\d\/\d\/\d{4}.*?\)(?=,|$)` with this `s` i.e, `.` matches new line characters option

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/mF6sO0/1)

You can use `split()` with this regex to get the 2 values separately.

Comment: When i use Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\d\/\d\/\d{4}.*?\)(?=,|$)"); It shows "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"

Comment: @user3669712 - Try `\\d+.\\d+.\\d{4}.*?\\)(?=,|$)` with `split()` and let me know if it works.